# Round the values in some columns in a .csv file using R

Tags: r, csv, rounding

I want to round the values of some columns containing "DTF." to 0 decimal in a .csv file using R and then write the rounded values back into the file using R. I am using RStudio v0.99.489 in win7.

Below is part of the headings of the file:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it faster directly in Excel?

Comment: `df <- read.csv( ... )`, `df[grep('DTF', names(df))] <- round(df[grep('DTF', names(df))])`, `write.csv(df, ... )`.

Comment: Thanks alistaire very much! The code worked quite well.